# I want to customize tomcat settings in Intellij Ultimate IDE

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij Ultimate ide 2020.1.

Several applications are being developed, and each Tomcat configuration exists.
I would like to set it up by creating a separate `server.xml` as I have experienced in Eclipse. However, I haven't seen documents or articles from people with similar experience.

Is there a way? Or I want to set up ssl so please let me know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: you need to create several different Tomcat server Run/Debug configurations for each app: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html

Comment: @PetrRastegaev, Thanks for the reply. But I want to know more. When I looked up, I didn't know exactly.

Comment: You should be considering spring-boot at this point in time. Deploying directly to tomcat is an outdated approach because it is difficult to develop (as you are discovering), maintain, and scale.

Comment: Of course that's good, but I think switching to Spring Boot is a separate story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it by configuring a new Tomcat for each application.